# stationary distribution of a markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am trying to find all the stationary distributions of the $3\times 3$ transition matrix below. because of the third state, the chain isn't irreducible however that isn't a sufficient condition for there not to be a stationary distribution.

I have used $\pi\mathbb{P}=\pi$ to work out $\pi=(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$ but I fail to get a solution even with  the knowledge that $\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=1.$ I am not sure where I am going wrong.

$$\mathbb{P}=\pmatrix{
 0.4      & 0.6      &0\\
 0.2      & 0.8      &0\\
0         & 0      & 1\\
}$$

solving the three simultaneous equations, I get $\pi_1=1/3\pi_2$ and
$\pi_3=1-2/3\pi_2$ i don't know where to go from there

the fact that the third state is an absorbing state not connected to the other two states is why i have come to a dead end but i am not sure how to find the stationary distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline:

Your transition matrix shows two non-intercommunicating subclasses $C_1 = \{1,2\}$ and $C_2 = \{3\}.$ So consider two separate chains.

The steady state vector for $C_1$ is $\sigma_1 = c(.75,.25).$ [Show how to derive this; then verify $\sigma_1 C_1 = \sigma_1,$ as required.]

> For more complicated, multi-state, irreducible ergodic chains, you may be interested in a computational method of finding steady state vectors. In R, you can find the steady state vector of an irreducible ergodic chain as shown below. (R finds right eigenvectors,
> hence the transpose `t`.) The first eigenvector listed in output is *proportional* to steady state vector. (Code `as.numeric` strips away complex
> number notation, irrelevant here, in case some eigenvectors are complex.)

```
P = matrix(c(.4,.6,.2,.8), nrow=2, byrow=T)
P
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.4  0.6
[2,]  0.2  0.8
eigen(t(P))
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1] 1.0 0.2
$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.3162278 -0.7071068
[2,] -0.9486833  0.7071068

g =as.numeric(eigen(t(P))$vec[,1]);  g
[1] -0.3162278 -0.9486833
sg = g/sum(g);  sg
[1] 0.25 0.75
sg%*%P
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.25 0.75
```

Consequently, if $0\le q\le1,$ then any 3-vector of form $\sigma = ((1-q)\sigma_1,q)$ is steady state for the entire chain. [Verify that $\sigma P = \sigma$ for such a vector.]